# Sorting filtered results based on word occurrence using Django Model Filter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

Platform: Django 1.1, Python 3.6 on a Linux server, backend is MySQL.

I'm after a fairly common functionality but I need guidance to where/how to begin this:

I have a model object called `Article`. I'm trying to implement a search function that retrieves articles based on searched terms, and then sort based on occurrences of words in the searched term.

In `Article`, I have the following fields that I'd like to sort or 'prioritise' based on:

```
- name, a text field
- keywords, also a text field but would contain comma-separated words
- article_text, a text area field that will contain the article itself
```

I want to basically sort the most relevant article to the least relevant, based on the searched terms input against name, keywords, and occurrences of words in article_text.

In my `views.py` I have this function that triggers on `request.POST`:

```
    form_data['search_term'] = request.POST.get('search_term')
    #removing question mark from term
    search_term = search_term.replace("?","")

    #Converting terms to a list of words, then converting all words to lowercase
    search_terms_list = search_term.split(' ')
    search_terms_list = [x.lower() for x in search_terms_list]
    #Fetching results
    results = Article.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, 
       [Q(name__icontains=word) | Q(keywords__icontains=word) | Q(article_text__icontains=word) for 
       word in search_terms_list]))
```

I am retrieving the right results but sorted based on article PK, which makes sense. Is there a way I can achieve the aforementioned without having to go to a 3rd party plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a table in which you save the articles and the number of times a word is retrieved inside each article, then you order that table by the number of times the searched term is retrieved, in descendand order, and pass it to your template.